# Transfer Money to NRO account via third party

Tags: india, money-transfer, singapore

I moved to Singapore recently. Can I transfer fund to NRO account via third party remittance service like Instarem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can transfer funds into NRO account from overseas. There is no restriction.